# Logging in with my openid creates a new account

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, login

This is my real account: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/84535/dykam. But after logging in, meta created a new account (huh?). Something similar happened on stackoverflow.com too, but there I could click "Create a new account" away, and it seemed I was logged in normally.

What could have gone wrong? This isn't really... nice.

Note: It happened at two different physical places.

Comment: Note: I can login with my google openid. Happy now I've two open id's linked. But still.

Answer (score 1):

I merged your accounts.. just mail the address at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You mean, my own email address? Don't get you really. Or the team at stackoverflow.com address?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for merging them.

Comment: He mentioned it for future viewers of this question.